# Trying to view video, getting wrong player

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

So I'm trying to watch the olympics coverage on the cbc website olympics.cbc.ca.

When other people in my office view a page like this one:

http://olympics.cbc.ca/videos/gold-medal-performances/videos/video/canada-thompson-serwa-win-gold-silver-ski-cross.html

they get an object element and a flash player. When I attempt to view this page however, I get a figure element like this:

Les Canadiennes Marielle Thompson (gauche) et Kelsey Serwa expriment toute leur joie après avoir passé la ligne d'arrivée. (Photo : AP/Andy Wong)

This happens regardless of which browser I use. I've tested in IE, firefox and chrome. I've even tested running through firefox with an SSH tunnel in case the IT guys were doing something.

Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Did you install FlashPlayer?

Comment: Yes, flash player is definitely installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think about 2 possible solutions to your question:

Do you use the newest Player-Version? Had that issue, to, when I forgott to upgrade my flash player...Does your flash player work on other sites using it?

On the other hand it could also be possible that you simply deactivated the flash player or accidently blocked the content from the page you are visiting.

Comment: So the issue was that I didn't have the IE version of flash installed. Now it's working on IE, still not on chrome. I'm wondering if maybe there's some kind of setting in chrome I flipped along the way that ignores flash or tries to do html5 automatically.

Comment: Just visit the Flash Player Homepage and download the whole software to your computer! If Chrome had the same problem as your IE the problem will be solved surely. If this is not any solution your idea that chrome might ignore flash or some other html elements can be true. Just look in the chrome settings if you have blocked any content or pages...

Comment: Well I just took a look into the documentation of Chrome. Google says that these plugins get blocked by Chrome automaticly if the software is not on the newest version:


    Java, 
    RealPlayer, 
    QuickTime, 
    Shockwave, 
    Windows Media Player, 
    Adobe Reader vor Adobe Reader X, 
    Unity, 
    Google Update, 
    VLC.


You can check your plugin settings by typing:

chrome://plugins

in your browser.

Comment: Just went to my chrome plugins page and flash is definitely there and enabled. It's also at the latest version. I also went to the flash about page (http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) and it says I have flash and its at the latest. Also got the little flash animation they put up there. I would think that this is an issue with CBC, except my chrome at home plays fine.

Comment: Totally forgot to ask that are you using a Mac? People wrote in the google forums about a similar problem and got a solution by a) updating their OS to the newest version or b) deinstall chrome and delete all the data and do a reinstallation of the software

Comment: no, I'm not running a mac. The second option scares me, but if I get this issue with a more important site, I'll probably end up trying it. Thanks for the help